# Php return add a span class

Tags: php, woocommerce

I need to add a span  in this code

```
return $button_text . ' - '. strip_tags( $product_price );
```

when I do that :

```
return $button_text . ' - <span class="Price">'. strip_tags( $product_price ) . ' </span>';
```

EDIT 1 :

This is the complete code :
I need to add a class price because I don't display my price on my shop. I put it one the button but google merchant don't find the price so I need to add my price into the return.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_add_to_cart_price', 20, 2 ); // Shop and other archives pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_add_to_cart_price', 20, 2 ); // Single product pages
function custom_add_to_cart_price( $button_text, $product ) {
    // Variable products
    if( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        // shop and archives
        if( ! is_product() ){
            $product_price = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_variation_price() ) ) );
            return $button_text . ' - From ' . strip_tags( $product_price );
        } 
        // Single product pages
        else {
            return $button_text;
        }
    } 
    // All other product types
    else {
        $product_price = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product ) );
        return $button_text . ' - ' . strip_tags( $product_price );
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The place this gets returned _to_, appears to apply escaping of HTML characters. Which means, you would need to make a change in that location as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$button_text ='Submit';
$product_price =10;
return  $button_text.'-<span class="Price">'. strip_tags( $product_price ) .'</span>';
```

Comment: If I do that, the code is displaying on the front page.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it